8% of Date/Time Strings are converting with the wrong year and month, no clue why
I'm trying to calculate the duration between the start and end dates, which seems simple enough. The issue is that the formats are variable. I created some functions to clean the strings and handle the different formats, but for about 8% of the dates or so (from what I can tell), the conversions are inaccurate. I'm really hoping someone can help with this.
Data
data <- read.csv('justDates.csv',
                 na.strings=c("","NA"))


## FUNCTIONS -----------------------------------------

# clean text
# don't judge me, I hate regex and this is hella ugly but gets the job done. Maybe. 
clean_dates <- function(datetime_string) {
  # Normalize timezones by removing all mentions of timezone abbreviations except UTC
  datetime_string2 <- gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "", datetime_string)  # Remove extra timezone notes in parentheses
  datetime_string3 <- gsub("(?<=\\d)(?=UTC|\\sUTC).*", "", datetime_string2, perl = TRUE)  # Strip trailing text after UTC
  datetime_string4 <- gsub("[\n\t]", " ", datetime_string3, perl = TRUE)  # Remove newlines and tabs
  datetime_string5 <- gsub("UTC\\s+", "UTC", datetime_string4, perl = TRUE)  # Clean trailing whitespace after UTC
  datetime_string6 <- gsub(" ?(UTC|GMT|UT)", "", datetime_string5, perl = TRUE)
  datetime_string7 <- gsub("[\\h\\v]+$", "",datetime_string6, perl=TRUE)
  return(datetime_string7)
  
}

#convert various date and time formats into one standard format
parse_date <- function(date_string){
  
  parse_attempts <- list(
    function(x) mdy_hms(x),
    function(x) dmy_hms(x),
    function(x) mdy_hm(x),
    function(x) dmy_hm(x),
    function(x) ymd_hms(x),
    function(x) ymd_hm(x)
  )

  # # Attempt each format, catching errors and returning the first successful conversion
  for (parse_fn in parse_attempts) {
    date <- tryCatch(parse_fn(date_string), error = function(e) NA)
    if (!is.na(date)) return(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date))) # Convert to consistent POSIXct format if successful
  }

  return(NA) # Return NA if no formats matched
  # Attempt to parse the date with each format
  
}
  


  
  
# Clean the Dates
df_dates <- data |> 
  mutate(
    start_date_clean=sapply(start_date,clean_dates),
    end_date_clean=sapply(end_date,clean_dates)
  )

# Convert to POSIXct
df_dates_posix <- df_dates |> 
  mutate(
    start_datePOSIX = sapply(start_date_clean, parse_date),
    end_datePOSIX= sapply(end_date_clean, parse_date)
  )

# Check dates are correct
df_dates_comp <- df_dates_posix |> 
  mutate(
    neg=end_datePOSIX<=start_datePOSIX,
    start_date_rev=as_datetime(start_datePOSIX),
    end_date_rev=as_datetime(end_datePOSIX)
  )

test3 |> 
  filter(neg==TRUE) |> 
  nrow()

There are 119 dates where the end_date is smaller than the start_date. By comparing the *_date_rev columns to the *_date_clean columns, you can see that sometimes the conversions don't quite work. However, I have no idea why at this point. I'd appreciate any help or insight y'all can give. What am I doing wrong?
Output with erroneous conversions
Thank you!

The externally hosted data set in the question is too large to include. I've added the first 30 rows towards the end of this answer as a sample.
You can provide lubridate::parse_date_time() with a vector of formats to try and parse with. Applying the set below to the full data set misses 2 date entries which were ambiguous to me.
library(tidyverse)

# Specify the datetime formats in the dataset
orders <- c(
  'd B Y, H:M:S',
  'B d, Y, H:M:S',
  'B d, Y, H:M',
  'd B Y H:M',
  'd b Y H:M',
  'd B Y, H:M',
  'B d, Y, H:M:S'
)

df |>
  # Drop text after UTC
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace(., '(UTC).*', '\\1'))) |>
  # Parse datetimes
  mutate(across(everything(), ~parse_date_time(., orders))) 
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    start_date          end_date           
#>    <dttm>              <dttm>             
#>  1 2017-09-12 21:17:02 2018-02-28 02:31:00
#>  2 2012-05-15 03:01:23 2012-09-17 02:53:00
#>  3 2009-03-15 23:43:00 2009-03-28 19:13:00
#>  4 1985-07-29 21:00:00 1985-08-06 19:45:26
#>  5 1989-08-08 12:37:00 1989-08-13 13:37:08
#>  6 1991-08-02 15:02:00 1991-08-11 12:23:25
#>  7 1990-12-02 08:13:32 1991-05-26 10:04:13
#>  8 1994-01-08 10:05:34 1994-07-09 10:32:35
#>  9 1999-02-20 04:18:01 1999-08-28 00:34:20
#> 10 2001-10-21 08:59:35 2001-10-31 05:00:00
#> # ℹ 20 more rows

While none of the start_dates occur after end_dates in this small sample, 5 rows in the full data set are returned by this filter. Looking at the original data you will find rows suggesting an issue in the source data, such as:
25 May 2023 15:15:00 UTC 5 May 2023 16:37:00 UTC
Data
df <- structure(list(start_date = c("12 September 2017,\n21:17:02 UTC", 
                                    "15 May 2012, 03:01:23 UTC", "March 15, 2009, 23:43 UTC", "July 29, 1985, 21:00:00 UTC", 
                                    "August 8, 1989, 12:37:00 UTC", "August 2, 1991, 15:02:00 UTC", 
                                    "2 December 1990, 08:13:32 UTC", "January 8, 1994, 10:05:34 UTC", 
                                    "February 20, 1999, 04:18:01 UTC", "October 21, 2001, 08:59:35 UTC", 
                                    "2 September 2015\n04:37:42 UTC", "October 6, 1990, 11:47:15 UTC", 
                                    "May 7, 1992, 23:40:00 UTC", "December 2, 1993, 09:27:00 UTC", 
                                    "16 September 1996, 08:54:49 UTC", "2 December 1990, 08:13:32 UTC", 
                                    "15 September 1976,\n09:48:30 UTC", "June 5, 1980, 14:19:30 UTC", 
                                    "25 September 2019\n13:57:42 UTC", "June 17, 1985, 11:33:00 UTC", 
                                    "July 16, 1969, 13:32:00 UTC", "November 11, 1966, 20:46:33 UTC", 
                                    "27 June 1983, 09:12:00 UTC", "22 July 1987, 01:59:17 UTC", 
                                    "7 June 1988, 14:03:13 UTC", "July 31, 1992, 13:56:48 UTC", 
                                    "4 March 1994, 13:53:01 UTC", "22 February 1996, 20:18:00 UTC", 
                                    "November 11, 1982, 11:19:00 UTC", "November 8, 1984, 12:15:00 UTC"
), end_date = c("28 February 2018 02:31 UTC", "17 September 2012, 02:53 UTC", 
                "March 28, 2009, 19:13 UTC", "August 6, 1985, 19:45:26 UTC", 
                "August 13, 1989, 13:37:08 UTC", "August 11, 1991, 12:23:25 UTC", 
                "26 May 1991, 10:04:13 UTC", "July 9, 1994, 10:32:35 UTC", "August 28, 1999, 00:34:20 UTC", 
                "October 31, 2001, 05:00:00 UTC", "12 September 2015\n00:51 UTC", 
                "October 10, 1990, 13:57:19 UTC", "May 16, 1992, 20:57:39 UTC", 
                "December 13, 1993, 05:25:33 UTC", "26 September 1996, 12:13:13 UTC", 
                "10 December 1990, 06:08:12 UTC", "23 September 1976,\n07:40:47 UTC", 
                "June 9, 1980, 12:39:00 UTC", "3 October 2019, 10:59 UTC", "June 24, 1985, 13:11:52 UTC", 
                "July 24, 1969, 16:50:35 UTC", "November 15, 1966, 19:21:04 UTC", 
                "23 November 1983, 19:58:00 UTC", "29 December 1987, 09:16:15 UTC", 
                "17 June 1988, 10:12:32 UTC", "August 8, 1992, 13:11:50 UTC", 
                "18 March 1994, 13:10:42 UTC", "9 March 1996, 13:58:22 UTC", 
                "November 16, 1982, 14:33:26 UTC", "November 16, 1984, 11:59:56 UTC"
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
  start_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                           "collector")), end_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                 "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


This worked beautifully, thank you Seth!!
